# IllegalArgumentException: the error message does not make sense

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to debug a Java application that is relying on Reflection. Right now the error I get is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field DataStructures.StackAr.topOfStack to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:18)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:358)
```

THe last lines of the application running are:

```
Field f = classUnderTest.getDeclaredField(processFieldName(var));
f.setAccessible(true);
Long value = (Long) f.get(runtimeInstance);
```

The error message is a bit misleading and I am not sure why it is mentioning a `set` operation whereas I am trying to preform a `get`.

I am suspecting that the `runtimeInstance` is not an object of the expected class. But that error message is throwing me away.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any clues?

PS1: The exact line causing the exception is this one:

```
Long value = (Long) f.get(runtimeInstance);
```

PS2: `processFieldName(var)` processes the correct name of the field, i.e. it removes some artefacts from a string with the field name like `this.` and so on.

Comment: This might be an autoboxing issue, i.e. an `int` is wrapped by an `Integer` automatically.

Comment: (1) Check which line exactly produces the error. You wrote 3 lines. (2) what does processFieldName(var) return? (3) how does it correspond to the fields in classUnderTest?

Comment: What kind of field is it, anyway?

Comment: I concur with your suspicions about runtimeInstance.  Why don't you test for it?

Comment: tried using a debugger on eclipse or so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source of those accessors it seems that the class declaring the field is not assignable from the `runtimeInstance`'s class:

> if (!(this.field.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(paramObject.getClass())))
>      
>    throwSetIllegalArgumentException(paramObject);

`field` seems to be the field you want to get from the instance, `paramObject` is your `runtimeInstance`.

Thus, if the declaring class of the field isn't the class or a super class of the paramObject you'd get that message.

Any chance your `paramObject` is an `Integer` here?

Edit: here's some source code from OpenJDK (should be similar to Oracle's), to explain the message:

```
  protected String getSetMessage(String attemptedType, String attemptedValue) {
         String err = "Can not set";
         if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
             err += " static";
         if (isFinal)
             err += " final";
         err += " " + field.getType().getName() + " field " + getQualifiedFieldName() + " to ";
         if (attemptedValue.length() > 0) {
             err += "(" + attemptedType + ")" + attemptedValue;
         } else {
             if (attemptedType.length() > 0)
                 err += attemptedType;
             else
                 err += "null value";
         }
         return err;
     }
```

Taking your message `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field DataStructures.StackAr.topOfStack to java.lang.Integer` we find that:

- the field is of type `int`
- the field's name is `topOfStack` in class `DataStructures.StackAr`
- `attemptedType` is `java.lang.Integer`

Since `attemptedType` is the type of your `runtimeInstance` I suspect `classUnderTest` is  `DataStructures.StackAr` whereas `runtimeInstance` is of type `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: A very complete answer, thank you. I will follow that path, I had a suspicion but the error message wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The java source for the err you're getting at the top of the stack would seem to indicate that runtimeInstance is not the same class as classUnderTest:

```
protected void ensureObj(Object o) {
                 // NOTE: will throw NullPointerException, as specified, if o is null
                if (!field.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {
                     throwSetIllegalArgumentException(o);
                 }
             }
```

Comment: @user102008 but then, it won’t throw a `NullPointerException` when `o` is `null`. As the comment indicates, this is intentional. Besides that, there is no point in suggesting improvements for cited code.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message carefully: "Can not set **int** field DataStructures.StackAr.topOfStack to java.lang.**Integer**"

You need to change the `Integer` to an `int` before assigning it.

Comment: I don't think I understand your suggestion. I am not trying to assign anything. I am just trying to get the value.

Comment: @rossum but where is he trying to use the Integer?

Comment: The JVM obviously sees him using an integer, otherwise it would not have issued that error message.  I would need to see the detailed class declarations to tell which particular field is declared as `Integer`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you're wrong. The doc for `java.lang.Field.getObject` and `set` explicitly allows (un)wrapping. If I understand the accepted answer, it's about confusing the object and its field.