# Can not set java.lang.Integer field to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, hql

User declaration:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    ....
```

Pattern declaration:

```
@Entity
public class Pattern {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;
    ...
```

UserPatternDeclaration:

```
public class UserPattern {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pattern_id")
    Pattern pattern;
    ...
```

request to database:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("from UserPattern where user = :user_id and pattern = :pattern_id ");
query.setParameter("user_id", userId);
query.setParameter("pattern_id", pattern_id);
List<UserPattern> list = query.list();//exception throws here
```

I got following exception:

```
 ...
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field 
    com.....s.model.User.id to java.lang.Integer
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    ....
```

Please help to fix this issue.

error message looks very very strange.

I have read related topic [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693950/illegalargumentexception-the-error-message-does-not-make-sense) but I don't found out answer.

### P.S.

hibernate log(before exception):

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        userpatter0_.id as id1_2_,
        userpatter0_.amountSearched as amountSe2_2_,
        userpatter0_.amountplayed as amountpl3_2_,
        userpatter0_.pattern_id as pattern_4_2_,
        userpatter0_.user_id as user_id5_2_ 
    from
        UserPattern userpatter0_ 
    where
        userpatter0_.user_id=? 
        and userpatter0_.pattern_id=?
```

In browser I see following message:

```
HTTP Status 500....could not get a field value by reflection getter of...model.User.id
```

Comment: Do you have getters and setters for that id field?

Comment: Yes, I have getters and setters for all fields

Comment: What's up with the difference in "patern_id" and "pattern_id"?

Comment: @Pimgd - fixed, recreate database tables(drope and then create) but I see old result

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Can you retrieve an empty result set without problems using that code?
Can you retrieve a User object by doing a from user where id = ? query?

Comment: 1.mysql 2.don't understand what do you want

Comment: 3.**Query query1 = session.createQuery("from User where id= 1");
  System.out.println(query1.list());** - this code works good

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What happens if you change your HQL query to `from UserPattern where user.id = :user_id and pattern.id = :pattern_id`?

I think Hibernate is confusing objects and ID fields.

Comment: It is enough strange because I know that **HQL uses class name instead of table name, and property names instead of column name.** UserPattern hasn't user.id property.

Comment: No but the idea is this:
If everything was public... what would you need to call to get to the user's id? UserPattern.user.id! So that's why it's user.id.

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify your query as follows:

```
from UserPattern where user.id = :user_id and pattern.id = :pattern_id
```

In your query, you are trying to match a `User` object with an `Integer` object.

Comment: It is enough strange because I know that **HQL uses class name instead of table name, and property names instead of column name.** UserPattern hasn't user.id property.

Answer (score 1):

If your field name is "id", your getter and setter methods should be named

```
public Integer getId(){return id;}
public void setId(Integer id){this.id = id};
```

If your are using Eclipse, generate the getter/setter by *right click -> Source -> Generate Getters and Setters...*

Make sure your getters and setter are public. Also you should add **@Table**-Annotation to all your Entities

Comment: Oh. It's true. @Table annotation allows to specify the name of the table and some other details. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Table.html

Answer (score 0):

i think maybe your annotation should be

@ManyToOne(TargetEntity=....class)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for days and have finally found the answer.
You used to be able to tell Hibernate what type the parameter was by using alternatives to `setParameter()` such as `setInteger` etc.  But these are now **deprecated**.

The problem is Hibernate is failing to interpret the type correctly for some reason. But there is an overloaded version of `setParameter` which allows you to *set the type directly*.

Firstly import the types:

```java
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;
```

Then use the following syntax to set the Parameter:

```java
q.setParameter("name", variable containing the value, StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER);
```

So in your case this would look like:

```java
q.setParameter("user_id", userid, StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER);
```